# Insertar tabulación en una cadena de texto

Tags: python

Se que si pongo \n se genera un salto de línea.

```
print('Hola \n mundo')
```

¿Pero se puede tabular? Por ejemplo que el mundo este tabulado.

Se que debe ser muy básica, pero hoy lo pensaba y no veo como hacerlo sin que sea una chapuza como por ejemplo meter espacios en medio.

```
print('Hola \n       mundo')
```

Comment: `\t` es el codigo de tabulador.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si necesitas hacer tabulaciones entre cadenas, al igual que otros lenguajes, podés usar "\t"

por ejemplo:

```
print('hola\tmundo')
```

---

```
hola    mundo
```

Ahora si tu intención es hacer el salto de linea y la tabulación a la vez simplemente podés combinar las dos.

por ejemplo:

```
print('hola\tmundo\nhola\tpython')
```

---

```
hola    mundo
hola    python
```